# php/html/js editor

Tags: text-editors, ide

I have few questions about ubuntu editors

1. how good is [scribes](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/) for web development
2. Also do netbeans or eclipse or komodo edit have a WYSIWYG plugin or something like dreamweaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Komodo is based on Mozilla platform, tends to bloat in the memory. Sometimes becomes unresponsive for no apparent reason;
- yes there is WYSIWYG;

Answer (score 0):

> I have few questions about ubuntu editors

You have seven questions. It might be better to ask them as several separate superuser questions. You could group the Komodo questions together. You could group the Netbeans questions together.

> how good is scribes for web development?

No idea, but I watched the first tutorial video about zencoding and sparkup in scribes. Since sparkup is available for my favourite editor, vim, I haven't yest seen a compelling case for switching. Scribes looks good.

> What about the memory footprint of komodo edit?

I don't know, sorry.

> is [komodo edit] fast enough?

Sorry, no idea, Fast enough for what?
Activestate say "Komodo Edit is a **fast**, smart, free and open-source code editor." (my emphasis)

> How much can i speed up Netbeans

What did you have in mind? More memory and faster processors will speed it up considerably. Not loading lots of addons may help too. Hard to quantify. What sort of netbeans operations do you need to speed up?

> can i change the icon set of netbeans

It is open source, so yes. I don't know how though.

> does netbeans have a WYSWYG plugin like dreamweaver

None that I know of.

> does komodo have a WYSWYG plugin like dreamweaver

Not as far as I know.